# Is the order of execution of operations in Javascript guaranteed to be the same at all times?

Tags: javascript, language-lawyer

When I do something like this:

```
var x = 5;
console.log(         x  + (x += 10)  );  //(B) LOGS 10, X == 20
console.log(  (x += 10) +  x         );  //(A) LOGS  0, X == 30
```

The difference in the returned value between (A) and (B) is explained by the value of `x` at the time it becomes evaluated. I figure that backstage something like this should happen:

```
     TIME ---->
(A)         (x = 5) + (x += 10 = 15) = 20
(B) (x += 10 == 15) + (x == 15)      = 30
```

But this only holds true if and only if `x` is evaluated in the same **left-to-right** order that it was written.

So, I have a few questions about this,

Is this **guaranteed** to be true for all Javascript implementations?

Is it defined to be this way by the standard?

Or, is this some kind of *undefined behavior* in Javascript world?

Finally, the same idea could be applied to function calls,

```
var x = 5;
console.log(x += 5, x += 5, x += 5, x += 5); // LOGS 10, 15, 20, 25
```

They also appear to be evaluated *in order*, but is there a stronger guarantee that this should always happen?

Comment: Does this help, or is your question specifically asking about operator execution order only? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14863430/does-javascript-have-undefined-behaviour

Comment: I'm asking particularly about guaranteed/predictable execution order. But that was a nice resource, didn't knew about those things. Thanks.

Comment: I believe this should clear up any questions https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence

Comment: Thanks Hogan. Following the syntax from that article, I'm trying to know if, when `(a OP b)` is to be evaluated, I can rely the value in `a` being evaluated/read before `b`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this guaranteed to be true for all Javascript implementations?

Yes.

> Is it defined to be this way by the standard?

Yes, you can read it yourself [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/).

Specifically, the [runtime semantics: evaluation of the addition operator (`+`)](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-addition-operator-plus-runtime-semantics-evaluation) specify that the left expression is evaluated before the right expression.

It's the same for the [evaluation of argument lists](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-argument-lists-runtime-semantics-argumentlistevaluation).

> Or, is this some kind of undefined behavior in Javascript world?

Yes, [there is undefined behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14863430/does-javascript-have-undefined-behaviour) in JavaScript, but not here.